# Flip jpeg Image loss quality

Tags: c#, image, jpeg, flip, lossless-compression

I flip a image(12M), find the image size increase to 26M  and the image format is changed to png. I save it to jpeg with the imageformat but the image size  reduce to 2M.  the code as following.

```
public void Flip(Bitmap map)
{  
   bmp.Save("d://image1.jpg") //12M

   RotateFlipType rft = RotateFlipType.Rotate180F

   bmp.RotateFlip(rft);
   bmp.Save("d://image2.jpg") //26M

   bmp.Save("d://image3.jpg",ImageFormat.Jpeg) //2M

}
```

If i want the new image has the same size with the orignal image, how can i do?

I try to save the image with the EncoderParameters, but i can't get the valid EncoderParameterList from the orignal image and i open the image3.jpg by image tools, i find its quality is 75 (orignal image is 100L), and subsampling is ON(orignal image is OFF,how can i set this).

thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for [JpegBitmapEncoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/System.Windows.Media.Imaging.JpegBitmapEncoder.aspx)? The rotate and flip there should be lossless.

Comment: I'm not sure that the size is actually always an indicator of quality.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you use a lossless JPEG flipping library, You should examine the parameters of the original JPEG file. Use those as the output parameters.

Specifically, the sampling (in the SOF marker) and the quantization tables (DQT marker) should be the same to get the best results.

There are a number of programs out there that will dump the contents of a JPEG stream so that you can see what these parameters are.

"Quality" is a completely meaningless figure in JPEG. That is simply a shorthand many JPEG encoders use to select quantization tables. A 75 figure in one implementation could be something completely different in another.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
var jgpEncoder = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg);
var myEncoder = System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality;

var myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
var myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 75L);
myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;

bmp.Save(@"d://image2.jpg", jgpEncoder, myEncoderParameters);
```

Also see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882583%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for reference

Comment: I try it, and i set the quality to 100L, image size is 8M (orignal image is 12M), may be i also need to set subsampling, but i can't find where to set it.

Comment: I try this:                                                        var encList = bmp.GetEncoderParameterList(info.Clsid);
RotateFlipType rft = RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipY;
bmp.RotateFlip(rft);
bmp.Save("d://image3.jpg", info, encList);                              there is a exception: parameters is void.